# Determine all the integers $x$ that have the property that $\sqrt{x^2+7x+21}$ is a rational number.

Tags: rational-numbers, square-numbers

**the question**

Determine all the integers $x$ that have the property that $\sqrt{x^2+7x+21}$ is a rational number.

**the idea**

The number would be rational only if $x^2+7x+21$ would be a square number which means that $x^2+7x+21=k^2 => k^2-x^2=(x+k)(k-x)=7(x+3)$.

From here i thought of going with divisibilities, but got nothing useful. Idk what to do froward. Hope one of tou can help me! Thank you!

Comment: A natural first step might be to do a quick search.  It's painless and might shed some light.

Comment: Try multiplying by 4 and completing the square.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there is a solution by completing a square, I want to present another way. We have that $x^2+7x+21$ is a square of an integer.

Let $x>0$. Then $$(x+3)^2< x^2+7x+21< (x+5)^2.$$ It means that $$x^2+7x+21=(x+4)^2.$$ This gives $x= 5$. Now let $x\le-9$. Then $$(x+4)^2< x^2+7x+21< (x+3)^2+12<(x+2)^2.$$

So we have that $$x^2+7x+21=(x+3)^2.$$ This gives $x= -12$. Now we just try all $x$ from $\{-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0\}$ and find that $x=-3$ and $x=-4$ work, too. So the answer is $x\in\{-12,-4,-3,5\}$.

Comment: smart ! (+1) $ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: @Aig Why cant we put the second case if $x \leq -5$?... Wouldnt it be still correct and more easier for us? Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: $x$ is chosen in such a way that the distance between $(x+3)^2$ and $(x+2)^2$ is more than $12$. The distance between $36$ and $49$ is $13$. So $|x+3|\ge 6$.

Answer (score 5):

For some integer $y$, we have $(2y)^2=4(x^2+7x+21)=(2x+7)^2+35$. Factorizing the difference of squares then gives four possible values for $\{2y+2x+7,2y-2x-7\}$: namely $\{\pm35,\pm1\}$ and $\{\pm7,\pm5\}$. Subtraction to eliminate $y$ correspondingly yields four values for $4x+14$, namely $\pm34$ and $\pm2$. Hence the possible values for $x$ are $-12,-4,-3,$ and $5$.

Answer (score 2):

Just use that there cannot be a perfect square  *between* two consecutive perfect squares (otherwise they would not be consecutive...) Then, for your  polynomial $p(x)=x^2+7x+21$ it is easy to see that for any integer $x>5$ you will have:
$$
  (x+3)^2 <  p(x) < (x+4)^2,
$$
so in that case p(x) itself cannot be a perfect square. With some minus-signs or other trickery you'll find a similar rule for negative $x$-values below a certain negative number (I leave the details to you!) That leaves just a small region of possible candidates around 0 to check by hand.

NB: by consecutive we mean next neigbors in the sequence of perfect squares, not that they have to be true neigbors of course (that happens only for 0 and 1!)

PS: I see @Aig beat me on this!